# Using javascript in xslt?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, transformation

In my XSL i have included a dropdown box which have values like,

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

If I select the value "one", then the template "one" should be applied.

```
<xsl:template match="one">
     <!-- code goes here -->
</xsl:template>
```

like wise two, three four and five should match their appropriate templates.
Is it possible using Javascript, so that onchange() method can get the selected value and call its own template.

If there is any other way, please suggest me.

Thanks,
jeyaa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the way client-side XSLT currently works. The XSLT is executed to generate (HTML + Javascript), and by the time any user interaction occurs, the XSLT has finished its job. I'm trying to change that model with Saxon-CE, but that's in the future.

For the moment, the best that you can do is catch the event in Javascript, and have the Javascript invoke a new XSLT stylesheet transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an XSLT jQuery plugin like the xslt pack (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-reference/source/browse/trunk/jQueryReference.wdgt/Assets/js/jquery.xslt.pack.js?r=7)

you can then do something like :

```
$(".myDiv").xslt(xmlData.xml, xslData.xml);
```

and change the xslData.xml with the xsl stylesheet you want depending on what has been clicked.